# Can LED Power Supply accept different gauge wires at the same time?

Tags: led-strip

We have under cabinet lighting with this: [image: 24 Volt LED Power Supply, 60 Watt, White]

It's in the middle of the kitchen on strip of under cabinet lighting goes to the left and one to to the right, black splices together with the black and red with the red and they going into that Armacost. We've had for 8 years, and now want to add an additional led strip. The previous brand is no longer sold, but this will be spec wise all the same except for the gauge of the wire coming out. The gauge would be 18. Vs the existing ones that has a 16 or 14 gauge it looks like. Looks ever so slightly bigger than 16 guage so assuming 14 guage.

Can we simply splice in this additional 18 guage red and black into the Aramcost? So the armacost red hole would have the 2 existing 14 gauge wires in it and now also a 18? And the black hole would have the 2 existing 14 gauge wires in it and now also a 18?

Or would that cause any potential issues?

Ideally they would all be the same. But replacing all the existing wire would not be possible at this time. Getting a new third light strip that's the same guage would be seemingly easier, but to find one that is 24v, a certain light temp, a certain wattage, and many other specs to match the others, greatly limited our options so this one is perfect other than the guage.

Comment: Imo it's unlikely that this unit has been listed for multiple wires in each contact of the output screw terminal block, and as such your existing installation is probably no up to code - never mind now wanting to add more... But this question would be on-topic over at the [DIY SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/). It's not [on-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here as a 'use of consumer electronics' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using different wire gauges as long as they can all carry the full current of the power supply. If your power supply could output more current than what each wire is rated for, then a short at the end of a wire would be a fire hazard, and the wires would need fuses, but that's not the case here.

However you're never gonna fit 3 wires in these tiny screw terminals without making a mess. They look really small and close together, the wires are going to be in a bunch and you won't notice the little strand that got out and will cause a shirt. Maybe by joining the wires in a crimp ferrule before putting them in. Whether or not that's up to code is for you to check.

I recommend Wago 221:

[image]

But that needs a junction box.

If your strips have accessible terminals, you can always piggyback on the strips by soldering 2 wires to each terminal.

[image]

That would be safer than shoving so much wire in this tiny screw terminal because there is much more room do a clean job.

And if the strips have connectors, someone will sell you a T junction.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Jbox  required for SELV?  where are you reading that?

Comment: Junction box would be for aesthetics, if you want to hide the wagos, but for low voltage yeah it's not a matter of safety. A solder splice with heat shrink on top would be easier to hide perhaps..